# How to resolve "LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined"?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

How can I resolve the following linking error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined"
```

What I was trying to do is simply recompiling MySQL Storage engine example with Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky737ya4.aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not familiar with the 'MySQL Storage engine example' so dont know if its a library or a .exe etc. However, usually the linker is able to infer the correct entry point based on a combination of your settings for:

- Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System -> SubSystem, and
- Configuration Properties -> General -> Configuration type

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9t8842e.aspx