# C++ string override linking error

Tags: c++, string, linker, overriding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to resolve “LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169822/how-to-resolve-link-fatal-error-lnk1561-entry-point-must-be-defined)

I have class A and B like this and upon linking there is error: error LNK1561: entry point must be defined. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

class A 
{
public:
A(){}
~A(){}
string getName()
{ return name; }
void setName(string name)
{this->name = name;}
void write()
{
   cout << "Value:" << getName() << endl;
}
protected:
string name;
};

#include <string>
#include "A.h"
class B : public A
{
public:
B()
{
setName("B");
}
~B(){}
};

#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
B abc = B();
abc.write();

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
 }
```

I get following errors:

error C2039: 'name' : is not a member of 'A'
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'string'
error C2065: 'cout' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'endl' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'name' : undeclared identifier
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'getName'
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'name'
error C2660: 'A::setName' : function does not take 1 arguments
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please use the search before asking new questions. Many questions have already been asked and answered, and you may find you solution instantly.

Comment: You are missing this too: `using namespace std;`

Answer (score 2):

If that's all there is, there is no `int main()` defined, so their is no place for the code to be called from and no place to start.

Comment: I will edit my first post with main function, but still I get a lot of errors with it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the entry point of your application, which is usually:

```
int main()
{
 // code to declare an A and B object
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you don't show us the command, but if you're linking to make an executable (rather than a dll), you have to define a function `main`; that's what the runtime invokes when it starts the executable.

Answer (score 0):

You've not written `main()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to have a `main` method, which is the entry point into your program.