# Very first build error after installing Visual Studio 2013. fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I guess this is very simple actually, but since I'm newbie in C++ I'm unable to understand what I did wrong.
Most of answers (like answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070367/link-fatal-error-lnk1561-entry-point-must-be-defined-error-in-vc)) suggest this:

> project name -> Properties -> Expand Linker tab -> System ->
>   SubSystem:

and change subsystem to different types. I tried it, but it gave me another error:

```
fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

So I assume that is a wrong way.
When I created project I chose `Visual C++ -> General -> Empty Project`.

My main method is `int main();` and `return 0;`. I did it before in `Eclipse` and everything was fine.

Please, what I should to configure to launch my project successfully? Thanks.

This how it looks:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Source{
    int main(){

        cout << "out" << endl;

        return 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: did you actually define `int main();`?

Comment: Is it literally `int main();`? That's a declaration, you need to define the function and give it a body.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined ERROR IN VC++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070367/link-fatal-error-lnk1561-entry-point-must-be-defined-error-in-vc)

Comment: @MikeSeymour, no, no, not literally, it has body with just `cout` line and return 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may change it to:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//class Source{
    int main()
    {
        cout << "out" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
//};
```

Comment: There is no hint with "main". If I write it manually bulid did not succeed.

Comment: I post the new answer.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `class Source{` so you get:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "out" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Source{
     int main(){
         cout << "out" << endl;
         return 0;
     }
};
```

Your above code has your main inside of a class called Source.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "out" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

is the proper way to start it off, but if you want to include the source class you can also like this.

```
include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Source
{

};

int main(){

     cout << "out" << endl;

     return 0;
}
```