# "LNK1561 entry point must be defined" for simple program

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmath

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    int y = pow(2, x);
    cin>>x;
    cout<< y;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Why do I get a compile error? `LNK1561 entry point must be defined`

I am using Visual Studio Express.

Comment: The above code should compile successfully, so either your compiler is broken or you actually had some other sort of problem, e.g. a run-time error.  Your question should show exactly what error you are having.  Saying "it didn't run"  does not give any helpers a clue as to what problem you are having either.

Comment: "LNK1561 entry point must be defined"

Comment: Maybe you started a Win32 App project instead of a Win32 Console project. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17070787/1505939), although you want to change to console project; you don't want to change to `WinMain` as suggested in that answer because you are trying to write a console program

Comment: Also, what version of compiler are you using

Comment: @M.M Comments say Visual Studio Express. There are a couple of different things in play here, though, so I suggested purity ask a new question for the linking error. The original code contained a runtime error which was corrected by Inisheer's answer. The linker error was only mentioned afterward.

Comment: Inisheer's code ran after I clicked (high-light selected) the opened ".cpp" window within Visual Studio. The only window there was, by the way. I accidentally took notice of this, otherwise, I never would've known if it wasn't by casualty. Inisheer's correction was indeed the initial solution to my question. I apologize for my impatience towards your sites demands. Hopefully I'll appreciate the need for these enforced description standards as I stick around. Thank you.

Comment: LNK1561 is not a compiler error. It is a linker error.

Comment: @computerfreaker that comes in various versions

Comment: @jussij it's normal to say "compiler" to refer to all stages of the software which translates source code into executable

Comment: @M.M a compiler error is nothing like a linker error and I suspect one reason why the OP is struggling to fix the issue is he/she doesn't know this is actually a linker related issue. The code posted compiles and links just fine for me. I can even run the resulting executable, despite the fact it contains code logic errors. The accepted answer most certainly did not fix the LNK error reported in the original question. That removed a compiler warning: `warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'x' used`.

Comment: @jussij based on OP's comments it seems incorrect use of the IDE is the problem... he accidentally discovered a different way to build that linked properly although I'm not sure if that same method will scale to larger projects.

Comment: @M.M i have no doubt this is _an incorrect use of the IDE issue_ and my guess is the OP just recreated the project to fix the issue. The issue could have been fix by a simple change to the settings of the project, but since the OP thought this was a compiler issue, probably never have even opened that linker settings tab of the project. The reality is the code is so simple it does not need an IDE (that is how I tested it) and the accepted answer is wrong. There is no way that code change could have fixed the linked error reported.

Comment: @jussij yeah, OP said in comments to the accepted answer that he clicked somewhere different or something (which I guess means that the IDE compiled the file as a standalone console app when you do this or something)

Comment: The window with the code in it was open in Visual Studio,  but it was not selected (as with the tab highlighted) so everytime I clicked the debug button, it was returning the error message...

Comment: I was still getting or sorts of error messages today because of this. This will make it even clearer: BEFORE DEBUGGING IN VISUAL STUDIO CLICK ON THE TAB WITH THE CODE IN IT (MAKING SURE IS HIGHLIGHTED SELECTED) AND SAVE IT, THEN BUILD AND RUN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign a value to x before it is used

```
int x;
int y = pow(2, x); // <--- what is the value of x here?
```

Try getting the value of `x` from the input first.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    int y = pow(2, x);
    cout<< y; 
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You are more clever and useful than any of Visual Studio's error indications and syntax highlighting features.

Comment: @purity If you found this answer useful, you can accept it by clicking the little checkmark to its left. That will give you both you and Inisheer a little bit of reputation, and will indicate to any future readers that this was the most helpful answer in solving your problem.

Comment: It's still not compiling though. I think it has to do with Visual Studio which I already despise..

Comment: @purity Inisheer's code compiles and runs successfully for me in both Code::Blocks and Visual Studio. If you're still unable to compile the posted code, you may want to ask a separate question about that. Make sure your code matches Inisheer's first, though.

Comment: I copy pasted his. It didn't run. Visual Studio Express. Would you say Code::Blocks is a better application?

Comment: @purity It's different. I like some aspects of C::B better, I like some aspects of VS better. I think it's a matter of opinion which is "better", so I would suggest trying both if you're unsure. C::B is free so there's no harm in giving it a try.

Comment: Inisheer's code ran after I clicked (high-light selected) the opened ".cpp" window within Visual Studio. Which by the way was the only window there was in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x;
    //int y = pow(2, x);//(1)
    //cin>>x;//(2)

    //exchange the lines (2) and (1)
    cin>>x;//(2)
    int y = pow(2, x);//(1)
    cout<< y; 
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should explain what you changed and why, instead of just posting a code-only answer