# How to compile libprotobuf in Release/Debug x64 mode using Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, protocol-buffers

I am able to compile in win32 but i am getting below error when compiled in x64

> Error 1>------ Build started: Project: libprotobuf, Configuration:
>   Release x64 ------ 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be
>   defined

Can we really compile libprotobuf targeting x64?

any help is really appreciated

Comment: There are already a lot of questions on SO regarding LNK1561, for example, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1169822/2675154). Did none of their answers help you to isolate your problem?

Comment: At least it should be possible to compile libprotobuf for X64, as [someone](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/protobuf/iYLfUFS3-k4) seems to have managed it. This information was easy to find using Google, so please do more research before asking questions on SO.

Comment: @honk i tried to find using google and i found [link]("http://wiki.alliedmods.net/Compiling_libprotobuf#Windows"). It just says to change the runtime to "/MT" but that didnt work for me

Comment: I downloaded the source code of protobuf for windows. It has .vcproj file of libprotobuf. I opened with my VS2013 and built successfully with Release x86. Since my application needs 64 bit of that i tried to change targets and followed steps mentioned in the above mentioned Url but after successfully generating the .obj files i got this error at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using protobuf-2.6.0 where i was getting the issue. After migrating to Protobuf-2.6.1 i am able to generate libprotobuf.lib for x64.